# Can I create both MyISAM and InnoDB tables in the same database using Hibenrate hbm2ddl

Tags: mysql, hibernate, innodb, myisam, hbm2ddl

I need both MyISAM tables and InnoDB tables in my database, I am using hbm2ddl to create them. Can I create both MyISAM and InnoDB tables in the same database using Hibenrate hbm2ddl?
It seems that selecting the dialect forces me to use one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you wrote, Hibernate will generate InnoDB tables if you use the `MySQL5InnoDBDialect`:

```
public class MySQL5InnoDBDialect extends MySQL5Dialect {

    public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getTableTypeString() {
        return " ENGINE=InnoDB";
    }

    public boolean hasSelfReferentialForeignKeyBug() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Using this dialect will cause Hibernate to add the `ENGINE=InnoDB` at the end of the `CREATE TABLE` statements. But this is global setting, you can't tweak this behavior at the entity level.

To use hbm2ddl and mix both tables engines, my suggestion would be to ALTER specific tables after the facts. To do so, you could use [5.7. Auxiliary database objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-database-object). From the documentation:

> #### [5.7. Auxiliary database objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-database-object)
>
> Auxiliary database objects allow for
>   the CREATE and DROP of arbitrary
>   database objects. In conjunction with
>   Hibernate's schema evolution tools,
>   they have the ability to fully define
>   a user schema within the Hibernate
>   mapping files. Although designed
>   specifically for creating and dropping
>   things like triggers or stored
>   procedures, any SQL command that can
>   be run via a
>   java.sql.Statement.execute() method is
>   valid (for example, ALTERs, INSERTS,
>   etc.). There are essentially two modes
>   for defining auxiliary database
>   objects:
>
> The first mode is to explicitly list
>   the CREATE and DROP commands in the
>   mapping file:
>
> ```
> <hibernate-mapping>
>     ...
>     <database-object>
>         <create>CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger ...</create>
>         <drop>DROP TRIGGER my_trigger</drop>
>     </database-object>
> </hibernate-mapping>
> ```
>
> The second mode is to supply a custom
>   class that constructs the CREATE and
>   DROP commands. This custom class must
>   implement the
>   `org.hibernate.mapping.AuxiliaryDatabaseObject`
>   interface.
>
> ```
> <hibernate-mapping>
>     ...
>     <database-object>
>         <definition class="MyTriggerDefinition"/>
>     </database-object>
> </hibernate-mapping>
> ```
>
> Additionally, these database objects
>   can be optionally scoped so that they
>   only apply when certain dialects are
>   used.
>
> ```
> <hibernate-mapping>
>     ...
>     <database-object>
>         <definition class="MyTriggerDefinition"/>
>         <dialect-scope name="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect"/>
>         <dialect-scope name="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
>     </database-object>
> </hibernate-mapping>
> ```

Another option would be to (ab)use the [Hibernate import.sql feature](http://in.relation.to/9081.lace) to perform the `ALTER`.

Comment: Since support for setting the engine and adding indexes (other than foreign keys) is absent from the JPA spec running an ALTER script sounds acceptable.